# Static const anonymous union gives "uninitialized const" error using GCC 4.9.3

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, unions

When compiling the following:

```
const static union {
    float cMaskF;
    int cMask = -1;
};
```

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-5.2.0` succeeds, while both `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-4.9.2` and `4.9.3` give the following error:

> uninitialized const 'Uphil::Math::{anonymous}::' [-fpermissive]

However, the following also produces errors, understandably...

```
const static union {
    float cMaskF = 1.0f;
    int cMask = -1;
};
```

> multiple fields in union 'Uphil::Math::{anonymous}::' initialized
>
> initializations for multiple members of 'Uphil::Math::{anonymous}::'

So is there a way to get const static anonymous unions to compile consistently?  Is this a bug in the older version that was fixed, or is it "non-standard" code that I shouldn't expect to be portable?  This seems like a useful construct, regardless.

This is all compiled under C++11.  v5.2.0 succeeds without warning even with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you tried to make a const union?

Comment: Specifically, I'm using a float with all bits set to initialize some constants for a SIMD library.  There are many SIMD operations that treat floats as bitsets, such as comparisons and your standard bit operations.  While it's not necessarily what this question is about, I'd be glad to hear a better solution!

Comment: In C++ you can only safely use the last-set member of a union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this seems like a gcc extension to allow const anonymous unions. This works fine with later versions of gcc, for [example with gcc 5.2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/txU0XozmZUpIWVZi). It would seem the only way to get it working for older versions would be to use the [-fpermissive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) flag, which downgrades warnings on non-conformant code but that may not be desirable.

On the other hand if we try this code with clang it provides the following warning if we use the `-pedantic` flag (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/txU0XozmZUpIWVZi)*):

> warning: anonymous union cannot be 'const' [-Wpedantic]

and we can find a gcc bug report: [type-specifier const in declaration of anonymous union](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67006) which claims this is ill-formed due to `7.1.6.1` *[dcl.type.cv]*  which says:

> If a cv-qualifier appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the
>   init-declarator-list of the declaration shall not be empty.

and as far as I can tell this is correct. We are forced to have an empty *init-declarator-list* by the definition of an anonymous union from section `9.5` *[class.union]*:

> A union of the form
>
> ```
> union { member-specification } ;
> ```
>
> is called an anonymous union; it defines an unnamed object of unnamed
>   type.

Comment: Hmm, your point about the mutually exclusive specifications is pretty damning.  However, seems like they might as well report an error on any attempt to create a const union then (unless there's some valid case I'm missing), rather than allowing you to travel down the rabbit hole.  Ah well.